# How to execute multiple thread group parallelly in single test plan in JMeter using master slave configuration

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, master-slave, distributed-testing

In my JMeter script, there are 2 thread group in single test plan , I want to execute the script using distributed testing mode i.e. master slave configuration.

However, when I am trying to execute multiple thread groups parallelly in single test plan using master slave configuration then only one thread is running. Also, have unchecked the option "Run Thread Groups consecutively (i.e. one at a time)" of test plan.

Similarly, when executing the script without master slave configuration in normal mode, then  multiple thread group are running parallelly properly.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, normally it contains information regarding Thread Group and individual thread start and stop events. If the log is not too informative you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging).

The most common reasons for the Thread Group not running/starting are:

1. The Thread Group relies on an external file used by [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config). If the file is not present the Thread Group won't run. If this is the case you will need to copy the CSV file to all slaves
2. The number of threads in the Thread Group is dynamic and uses i.e. [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P). If you don't pass the property it will have either default value or it will be resolved to `1`. If this is the case you will need to pass the number of threads via [`-G` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) or put it to *user.properties* file on all slaves